If $f(x)= x^2 + ax+b$ and $f(2)+f(3)<2$, then what is the nature of roots of the equation $f(x)=1$?

If $f(x)= x^2 + ax+b$ and $f(2)+f(3)<2$, then what is the nature of roots of the equation $f(x)=1$?

I approached the question by taking into account the fact that at least one of $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ is less than $1$, but I got stuck.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

If $f(x)=1$ has no roots then since leading coefficient is positive, we will have $f(x)>1 \ \forall x \in \ \mathbb{R}$, which would mean $f(2)+f(3)>2$

Substitute in the information available
We are given that $ f(2) + f(3) < 2 $. Substituting that into the given equation we see that $ 13 + 5a + 2b < 2 $, which rearranging can be written as $ 5a + 2b < -11 $.
The nature of the roots:
The usual method for determining the nature of the roots for a quadratic is to use the discriminant. This is worth looking up if you are not familiar with it. For a quadratic in the form $ ax^{2} + bx + c = 0$, the discriminant is given by $ b^{2} - 4ac $.
Using the given quadratic in this case, we determine the discriminant when $ f(x) = 1 $, so $ x^{2} + ax+ (b-1) = 0$. The discriminant is therefore $ a^{2} - 4(b-1) = a^{2} - 4b + 4 $.
You should be able to take it from here, it is then just a case of comparing the inequality with the discriminant. The key points for this are:

If the discriminant is greater than zero, then there are two real roots
If the discriminant is zero then there is one real repeated root
If the discriminant is less than zero then there are no real roots

I have left the question at this point with the purpose that you should try the rest of it yourself, it would be good practice.
Best of luck.
